# Delete some part of a string in a column

Tags: r

I have a lot of records like "LISTA CIVICA | blablabla". They are character-class under the column "partito". I need to cut off the "| bla bla bla" in order to obtain for all the records just "LISTA CIVICA".

I need to obtain only LISTA CIVICA for all those records.

I tried this code but it does not work

```
gsub(pattern="",replacement = "LISTA CIVICA",ammcom$partito)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by the `|` (escape it as it is a metacharacter for OR (`|`) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\s*\\|.*", "", str1)
#[1] "LISTA CIVICA" "LISTA CIVICA"
```

Or another option is `regmatches/regexpr`

```
trimws(regmatches(str1, regexpr("^[^|]+", str1)))
#[1] "LISTA CIVICA" "LISTA CIVICA"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("LISTA CIVICA | INSIEME PER ALBERA", "LISTA CIVICA | blablabla")
```

Comment: I need to change all the record in that way...I tried but it is not still working...

Comment: @VitoFabrizioBrugnola  You need to change the `str1` with `ammcom$partito`.  Also, this is based on the example you showed

Comment: I reforumlate: I have a lot of records like LISTA CIVICA | blablabla. They are character-class under the column "Partito". I need to cut off the "| bla bla bla" in order to obtain for all the records just "LISTA CIVICA".

Comment: @VitoFabrizioBrugnola  You need to update your post.  Others won't know what your pattern will be if you just show one example

Comment: @VitoFabrizioBrugnola  That is what the regex is doing to match the `|` followed by any characters and replace it with blank

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be using lookaround expression:

```
library(stringr)
trimws(str_replace_all(text,"\\|(?>.*)",""))
```

OR

```
trimws(str_replace_all(text,"\\|.*",""))
```

**Output**:

```
 > trimws(str_replace_all(text,"\\|.*",""))
[1] "LISTA CIVICA" "LISTA CIVICA"
```

**Input data:**

```
text = c("LISTA CIVICA | INSIEME PER ALBERA","LISTA CIVICA | bla blabla")
```

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine found out how to fix my problem.

```
length(ammcom$partito[grep("^LISTA",ammcom$partito)])
L <- rep("LISTA CIVICA", 92033)
ammcom$partito[grep("^LISTA",ammcom$partito)] <- L
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string you want to keep is always the before the `|`, you can also split the string around `|` and retain only the first element:

```
str1 <- "LISTA CIVICA | INSIEME PER ALBERA"

unlist(lapply(strsplit(str1,"\\|"), function(x) x[[1]]))
```

Comment: Sorry man, i corrected my questione, I was not so cleare at the first attempt (my first question on Stack's)...be patient, please! ;)